# Can I close an InputStream, Reader, Writer... with less lines of code with Java 8+ than in Java 7 and lower?

Tags: java

What the way do close `Reader`, `InputStream`, and others using `Optional` or the Java 8+ features (lambdas ?).

Since years, I'm using the following code that works, but does a better way exists that needs less lines to write with Java 8+ ?

EDIT : I can't use try-with-resources in my case.

```
private Reader reader;

// Time to close the reader
if (this.reader != null) {
     try {
        this.reader.close();
     }
     catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
     }

     this.reader = null;
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

there is try with resources

```
    try(Reader reader = new StringReader(str)){
        //code
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

you don't need to close reader

Comment: You don't need to close the reader as long as you're using try-with-resources (as in this answer). Try-with-resources will automatically call `close()` when the reader goes out of scope. If you're not using try-with-resources (as in the original question) you still need to call `close()`.

Comment: Good answer. Since question is about Java 8+ vs older versions, you might point out that try-with-resources was added in Java 7, not Java 8. --- Also, *"you don't need to close reader"* is misleading, since you *do* need to close the reader, but the try-with-resources will do it for you, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: It is not the actual OP requirement. The field is initialized before.

Comment: For my specfic case, I am not closing the reader in the same function I'm reading it : I don't use a try-with-resources here. But the `close()` have to be done to allow the underlying reader to clean its environment.

Answer (score 0):

just use try with resources

```
 try (// resources that need to be close) {
    //code 
} catch (Exception e) {
 //code
}
```

Comment: I can't use try-with-resources. The file is not closed in the same function it is opened or read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a compact form in stock Java, which is why I've previously used [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html).  (Now I always use try-with-resources.)

```
// Time to close the reader.
IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
```

Note that in the current release this is deprecated in favor of try-with-resources, but you've implied that won't work for you.

Comment: Good idea. But `closeQuietly(...)` won't emit a warning in logs in case of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
private Reader reader;

private void workWithReader() {
    this.reader = ... ; // init

    // ... do some work with it ...

    // close 
    close(this.reader, e -> LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage(), e));
}

// this can be reused for all Closeables, not only Reader and InputStream
public static void close(Closeable closeable, Consumer<IOException> exceptionHandler) {
    if (closeable != null) {
        try {
            closeable.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            exceptionHandler.accept(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I can't. I my case, the reader "might" be opened by me, but not all the times. Sometimes its me, sometimes not. And the work to do between opening it and closing it vast and cannot be put into the same method.

Comment: @Marc you can place static method close (from code above) in any place and call it from any place